# Python - destroy class instance from another class

Tags: python, class, oop, tk-toolkit

I have a program set up with a navigation bar as its own class, and each different page is its own class as follows:

```
class Navigation...

class MainPage...

class page2...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global homepage
    root = Tk()
    homepage = MainPage(root)
    navigation = nav_page(root)
```

To load a new page, I try to delete the instance of the class, then recreating the other page in the function as follows:

```
class Navigation...
   def __init__(self,parent):
      mainpage_button = Button(parent, text='mainpage',command=self.load_main()).pack()

      secondpage_button = Button(parent, text='2ndpage',command=self.load_2nd()).pack()

   def load_2nd(self):
     global root
     global homepage
     del homepage
     2nd_page = page2(root)

   def load_main(self):
     global root
     global 2nd_page
     del 2nd_page
     homepage = MainPage(root)

class MainPage...

class page2...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global homepage
    root = Tk()
    homepage = MainPage(root)
    navigation = nav_page(root)
```

When I tried running this I get

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'MainPage' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know. It's referenced in the if name==, when I create the class, before it even loads the nav page, which deletes the class.

I added global, as I was getting desperate. I also tried using class.**del**, but that did not work either.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: And provide the stack trace with the error. It usually provides a line number, which will help you diagnose which line is creating the UnboundLocalError.